# A question about indices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a group. We want to prove  $|G:⋂_{1≤i≤r}C_G (g_i)|≤∏_{1≤i≤r}|G:C_G (g_i)|$, where $g_i$s are from $G$.

Whould be grateful for your helps and advices.

Comment: I have corrected the problem now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $H_1,H_2,\cdots,H_r$ is any list of subgroups of a group $G$ then consider the $G$-set

$$G/H_1\times G/H_2\times\cdots\times G/H_r.$$

This is a product of coset spaces, equipped with a left $G$-action. We do not assume any group structure on it, since we did not assume any of the $H_i$s were normal in $G$.

There is an element $x=(H_1, H_2,\cdots, H_r)$ in this product space; its stabilizer is the intersection of the subgroups, ${\rm Stab}(x)=\bigcap H_i$. Hence by orbit-stabilizer, ${\rm Orb}(x)\cong G/\bigcap H_i$ (as $G$-sets, but in particular purely set-theoretically, as in they are the same size), and this orbit must be bounded above in size by the size of the product space.

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, then the cosets of $H \cap K$ are of the form $aH \cap aK$. Thus $[G : H \cap K] \leq [G:H][G:K]$. The result for a finite collection of subgroups follows by induction.

Comment: Thanks. And I think even this is true that $[G : H \cap K] \leq min({[G:H],[G:K]})\leq[G:H][G:K]$

Comment: @Aref That's incorrect. In fact $[G:H\cap K]$ is $\ge$ both $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$. This is because $H\cap K\subseteq H$ and $\subseteq K$.

Comment: Yes, right, right. Thank you anon. I read your post either and understood it completely. It was nice; I wonder how our dear friend Mikko Korhonen deduced directly from forms of cosets of $H∩K$ that $[G:H∩K]\leq[G:H][G:K]$ ?

Comment: @Aref: Now $a(H \cap K) = aH \cap aK$, so any coset of $H \cap K$ is an intersection of the form $X \cap Y$, where $X$ is a coset of $H$ and $Y$ is a coset of $K$. There are $[G:H]$ possible choices for $X$ and $[G:K]$ possible choices for $Y$. Thus there are at most $[G:H][G:K]$ such intersections.

Comment: Afterwards I discovered it myself too, but again I want to thank you for your earnest attempt. Thanks